# Karate + Cucumber report missing Doc Strings for the called scenario responses

Tags: cucumber, karate, cucumber-junit

Cucumber report is missing the doc strings for the responses from a called scenario.

in a given scenario, i am calling multiple scenarios using Call ()
its printing randomly sometimes response from the called scenarios and sometimes not. This is preventing us visualizing the data flow between API in the test report.

Although the karate-log is having the response from that called scenario, its just the cucumber reporting is not printing it. we are using karate 0.9.4, cucumber reporting 4.6.0.

[When statement not printing Doc String](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJjTF.png)

I am trying to print it like this.

[When Statement with Doc string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3Bv0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with 0.9.6.RC3 - if it still doesn't work it is a bug and please follow this process (we need a way to replicate): https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue